# Insert NaoQI in ros file

Tags: ros, naoqi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my rosfile i want to use alproxies, which is in naoqi, but when i try to compile the almotionproxy.h is not find.

in my cmkaelist.txt i insert:

catkin_package(

INCLUDE_DIRS naoqi

)

include_directories(naoqi)

include_directories(

${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}

)

in my ros.cpp

include almotionproxy.h

have i forget something?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182813/insert-naoqi-in-ros-file/) by [Dante](https://answers.ros.org/users/12521/dante/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI,

If you want you can have a look to nao_driver which uses naoqi : https://github.com/keulYSMB/nao_robot/tree/devel/nao_driver
Please have a look at the CMatkeLists.txt and the cmake/FindNAOqi.cmake. You should be able to use the same layout for your package.

Cheers,
Mikael

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2014-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0